# .Net 4.8 Support for Windows 10 ends in 26 days?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I am trying to find out when (or approximately when) .Net Framework 4.8 will go out of support.

Microsoft's site says:

> .NET Framework is a component of the Windows OS. Components receive the same support as their parent product or platform. For more information, please visit the .NET Framework Lifecycle FAQ.

The [.NET Framework Lifecycle FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework) lists the versions of Windows that support .Net Framework 4.8:

- Windows 10 versions: 1607, 1703, 1709, 1803, 1809, 1903

  - The longest supported listed version is done on **12/8/2020** ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-10-enterprise-and-education))
  - 1909 is NOT listed
- Windows Server version 1803, 1903

  - The longest supported listed version is done on **12/8/2020** ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-server))
  - 1909 is NOT listed
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, 2012/R2, 2016, 2019

  - The longest supported listed version is done on **01/09/2024** ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-server-2019))

So it seems that for Windows 10 (what I use to develop on), **.Net Framework 4.8 goes out of support in less than a month**.  If I install one of the newer versions (like 1909) it is not a supported OS for .Net Framework 4.8 (at least according to the FAQ.)

It seems that I have several more years to run .Net Framework on a server, but, unless I want to actually do my development work on a Windows Server 2019 box, I will be out of support in 26 days.  And if I target a Windows 10 box to run my client applications on, I am also done in 26 days.

**Am I right or am I missing something?  Is it all over in 26 days (except for Windows Server)?**

Comment: Out of support means everything will continue to run, but not receive bug fixes and security patches. It's not 'all over'

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - True, but for a risk adverse medical company (like mine), being out of support is not an acceptable plan. (Most people are not ok putting their medical safety in the hands of unpatched software. :)

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-framework

Comment: @Vaccano From the page you linked "*.NET Framework 4.8 ...* ***is supported*** *as a Windows component* ***on the latest required update for*** *the operating systems below*". For 1903 for example "*the latest required update*" is going to become 1909 [on Dec 8, 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903). Meaning you'll need to update 1903 machines to 1909 before Dec 8th in order to maintain formal support.

Comment: .NET 4.8 is the latest version of .NET 4.x. Of course it's going to be supported on modern Windows for years.

Comment: @dxiv - So it is probably an oversight that the list of supported operating systems for 4.8 does not include 1909? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework#net-framework-48-supported-os)

Comment: @Vaccano I believe that's intentional, if rather confusingly worded. .NET 4.8 ["*follows the Lifecycle Policy of the parent OS*"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework-48) and 1909 is less than 18 months old, so it is fully supported in all editions. The list at the end appears to only include exceptions to the general rule, such as 1903 which is outside its [servicing period](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/windows#what-is-the-servicing-timeline-for-a-version-feature-update-of-windows-10) but still supported as far as .NET 4.8 goes.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, since Microsoft will not be releasing any new versions of .Net Framework, they have committed to [supporting 4.8 indefinitely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies):

> .NET Framework 4.8 is the last version of .NET Framework, and no further versions will be released. However, .NET Framework will continue to be serviced with monthly security and reliability bug fixes. Additionally, it will continue to be included with Windows, with no plans to remove it. You don't need to migrate your .NET Framework apps, but for new development, use .NET 5.0 or later.

Comment: This is only partially correct. Like the comments above indicated, the underlying Windows version must also fall into the supported list (Windows 10 1909 becomes the latest mininal), or Microsoft support won't be able to help in any way.